# Assign style attr through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to assign colors to these span buttons, if I put the class inside span class, it kind of works, but sometimes it doesn't change color, and also i want to be able to have set only one button as colored. And I also need to store the values inside style, because i want it to be colorized when i load the page.

```
while($stmt->fetch()): ?>
<div class="statusicons">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><span  data-color="0" class=" glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style=""></span></a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><span  data-color="1" class=" glyphicon glyphicon-road" style=""></span></a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><span  data-color="2" class=" glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" style=""></span></a>
    </div>
<?php endwhile;
$stmt->close(); ?>

$('.statusicons').on('click', function() {
    var color = $(this).data('color');
    var array = ['green', 'orange', 'red'];
    $(this).attr('style', 'color :' + array[color]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this is because of `data-color` returns string.

Try converting index to integer.

```
$('.statusicons a').on('click', function() {
  var color = parseInt($(this).data('color'));  // Convert data-color to integer to check index
  var array = ['green', 'orange', 'red'];
  $(this).attr('style', 'color :' + array[color]);
});
```

Comment: The array is not a problem, i am able to set the color, but sometimes after i click on the button, nothing happens and i also need to be able to assign color just to one of the three buttons.

Answer (score 0):

use `css()` ,change your click event to the link click and find that link's span and color it

```
$('.statusicons a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var color = $(this).find('span').data('color');
    var array = ['green', 'orange', 'red'];
    $(this).find('span').css('color',array[color]);

});
```

you can't save the state of the color in the style attribute, the state is lost at page refresh, don't forget to wrap your js in document ready statement and delegate your event if the status icons are dynamically added

Comment: @Bartek Gladys
It's doing same thing as before, I needed to add class to span, but i can change color of all 3 buttons, which i don't want, I want to be able to set just one button,  And also it sometimes doesn't work, when i click on the button nothing happens.

Comment: That somewhat works, but still, is it possible to somehow save the state ? and also I want just one of the three buttons to be able to be changed. For example if i set one button as red, then the other two buttons will reset their color

Comment: Do I need to use cookie ? or is there better solution ?

Comment: cookie, db, localstorage pick one

Answer (score 0):

try `css()`

```
$(this).css('color', array[color]);
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".